# Extracting data from contour plot

Tags: matlab, extract, contour

I want to extract the data in a contour plot that I have, especially the maximum number of (x,y) co-ordinates that make up the entire contour.

I have written the following code:

```
[c,h] = contour(xgrid,ygrid,Z,[4e-6,4e-6],'EdgeColor',[1 0 0],'LineWidth',2);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For the max just use: `max_num_coords = max(c(:,1));` if you want the total number you would make loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you call `contour` with 2 outputs, with the following format :

```
[M,h] = contour( )
```

`h` is the handle to modify contour properties, and

`M` contains the points you are looking for.

`M` has the following format

```
Z1, x_1_1, x_1_2, ..., x_1_N1, Z2, x_2_1, x_2_2, ..., x_2_N2, Z3, ...
N1, y_1_1, y_1_2, ..., y_1_N1, N2, y_2_1, y_2_2, ..., y_2_N2, N3, ...
```

`Zi` : height of i-th contour line

`Ni` : Amount points in i-th contour line

`(xij, yij)` : The points, coordinates of points i-th contour line and `j` ranges from 1 to `Ni`

all details explained here

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html?s_tid=srchtitle_contour_1#f19-795863_sep_mw_d9e727e2-79e4-4cf6-bfaf-431a164d82b0